# Confused about firebase and how to send messages

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a chat feature in my app using firebase in React Native.

The latest code I used to ensure that this is working was this:

```
const ChatScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation,route}) => {
  const [input,setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    db.collection('chats')
      .doc(route?.params?.currentUserId)
      .collection('messages')
      .add({
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        message: input,
        senderId: route?.params?.currentUserId,
        receiverId: route?.params?.otherUserId,
      })
      .then((docRef) => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setDocRef(docRef.id);
        }, 2000); // Add a delay of 2 seconds to allow document to fully write to the database
        setInput('');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db
      .collection("chats")
      .doc(route?.params?.currentUserId)
      .collection("messages")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
          const newMessages = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
          const filteredMessages = newMessages.filter(
            (message) => message.senderId === route?.params?.currentUserId
          );
          setMessagesSent(filteredMessages);
        } else {
          console.log("No messages found");
        }
      });
    return () => unsubscribe(); // Clean up the listener when component unmounts
  }, []);
      
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"white"}}>
      <StatusBar style="light"/>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} style={styles.container}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={90}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{padding: 15}}>
        {messages.map((message,id) => (
          <View key={id} style={styles.sender}>
            <Avatar 
              position="absolute"
              bottom={-15}
              right={-5}
              rounded
              containerStyle={{
                position:"absolute",
                bottom: -15,
                right: -5,
              }}
              source={{
                // uri: data.photoURL,
              }}
              size={30}
            />
            <Text style={styles.receiverText}>{message?.message}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
        <TextInput 
          value={input} 
          onChangeText={text => setInput(text)}
          onSubmitEditing={() => input.trim() !== "" ? sendMessage() : null}
          style={styles.textInput}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => input.trim() !== "" && sendMessage()} activeOpacity={0.5}>
          <Ionicons name="send" size={24} color="#2B68E6"/> 
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
          </>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

At the moment if I look at the simulator and expo go, I am getting the messages I send displayed but not the ones I receive.

What I am doing wrong here? Is there other way of displaying messages I should be using instead of above?

Comment: The idea is correct. You add a document via `collection(...).add(...)` and in another place you listen to the collection changes via `onSnapshot(...)`. Please check your logs, whether you receive any information in the `onSnapshot` method, e.g. `console.log(querySnapshot.docs)`, and correctness of field paths and parameters.

Comment: More improvements: 1) useEffect react hook requires dependency list, you are using `db`, so it should be `useEffect(..., [db])`, 2) It looks like you need the latest messages to retrieve during a subscription, not all messages, and in the reverse order (latest - first), so the filter can be `orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(5)` for the latest 5 messages.